# Echo whether a process is running on a range of remote computers

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to create a script that will connect to remote computers within an IP address range and then echo which of those is running the explorer.exe process.

When I run the script within a small range (10.2.1.1 - 10.2.1.10), I know that 10.2.1.4 is offline and that 10.2.1.9 and 10.2.1.10 are not Windows based computers and should therefore echo "Explorer.exe is not running" however that doesn't seem to be the case. They appear to return the same result of the previous server. For instance, 10.2.1.3 has 3 instances of Explorer.exe and echo's 3 times, I then get the same result for 10.2.1.4 which is offline.

My script is as follows:

```
On Error Resume Next

intStartingAddress = InputBox("Please enter a starting address: (e.g. 1)", "Starting Address")
intEndingAddress = InputBox("Please enter an ending address: (e.g. 254)", "Ending Address")
strSubnet = InputBox("Please enter a subnet excluding the last octet: (e.g. 10.2.1.)", "Subnet")

For i = intStartingAddress to intEndingAddress
    strComputer = strSubnet & i

    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = 'Explorer.exe'")

    For Each objProcess in colProcess
        If colProcess.Count > 0 Then
            Wscript.Echo strComputer & " Explorer.exe is running."
        Else
            Wscript.Echo strComputer & " Explorer.exe is not running."
        End If
    Next
Next

Wscript.Echo "That's all folks!"
```

Comment: Would a Non-Windows machine respond to this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What makes you believe that non-Windows computers would respond to WMI queries in the first place? For most non-Windows computers the statement

```
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
  & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
  & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
```

will simply fail, because they don't support WMI (which is short for Windows Management Instrumentation). Because of this error, the `objWMIService` object remains the same as it was in the previous loop cycle, so your subsequent instructions query the same host you did before. You never see the error, though, because it's masked by the global `On Error Resume Next`.

This can be mitigated by removing the global `On Error Resume Next` and changing this loop:

```
For i = intStartingAddress to intEndingAddress
  strComputer = strSubnet & i

  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

  ...
Next
```

into something like this:

```
For i = intStartingAddress to intEndingAddress
  strComputer = strSubnet & i
  Set objWMIService = Nothing

  On Error Resume Next
  Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" _
    & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
  On Error Goto 0

  If Not objWMIService Is Nothing Then
    ...
  Else
    WScript.Echo strComputer & " cannot be accessed."
  End If
Next
```

You can distinguish between unreachable computers and computers that don't appear to be running Windows by combining the above with a ping test:

```
Set wmi = GetObject("winmgmts://./root/cimv2")

qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PingStatus WHERE Address='" & strComputer & "'"
For Each ping In wmi.ExecQuery(qry)
  reachable = (0 = ping.StatusCode)
Next

If reachable Then
  If objWMIService Is Nothing Then
    'computer is not running Windows
  Else
    'computer is running Windows
  End If
Else
  'computer is offline
End If
```

Comment: I don't believe that non-Windows would respond, but my code does echo that explorer was running on them, when it should not.

Moving the "On Error Resume Next" and adding "On Error GoTo 0" as well as the "If Nothing Then" did the trick.

Comment: As explained above that's due to a misconception in your code. It claims that the currently processed host is running `Explorer.exe`, because it's actually querying a different host that is running `Explorer.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

First: I would move the colProcess.Count check to occur before the colProcess loop.  If there are no collections in the object you will not get an echo response.

Second:  I would test for a value within the WMI query such as ProcessID and check if it is Null or if it does have a value, meaning that it is actually running.

```
intStartingAddress = InputBox("Please enter a starting address: (e.g. 1)", "Starting Address")
intEndingAddress = InputBox("Please enter an ending address: (e.g. 254)", "Ending Address")
strSubnet = InputBox("Please enter a subnet excluding the last octet: (e.g. 10.2.1.)", "Subnet")

For i = intStartingAddress to intEndingAddress
    strComputer = strSubnet & i

    Set objWMIService = Nothing

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    On Error Goto 0

    If objWMIService Is Nothing Then
        Wscript.Echo strComputer & " Explorer.exe is not running."
    Else
        Set colProcess = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Process Where Name = 'Explorer.exe'")

        If colProcess.Count = 0 Then
            Wscript.Echo strComputer & " Explorer.exe is not running."
        Else
            For Each objProcess in colProcess
                If IsNull(objItem.ProcessID) Or Not IsNumeric(objItem.ProcessID) Then
                    Wscript.Echo strComputer & " Explorer.exe is not running."
                Else
                    Wscript.Echo strComputer & " Explorer.exe is running. (Process ID: " & objItem.ProcessID & ")"
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next

Wscript.Echo "That's all folks!"
```

EDIT:
Modified Script to take into account the WMI Query will fail on Non-Windows Operating Systems as pointed out by Ansgar Wiechers.

Comment: This does *not* solve the problem, because the issue is that `GetObject` fails for non-Windows computers. Because of that `objWMIService` retains its value from the previous loop cycle, and the query is run against the same computer as before, unsurprisingly producing the same result as before.

Comment: @ansgar-wiechers You make a good point and I apologize for the oversight; however, this could have easily been corrected.  I don't see why its worth down voting the answer, especially when I could have easily corrected it.

Comment: Answers that are factually wrong deserve being downvoted. When they are corrected they deserve being un-downvoted.